# SVG change cursor from `cursor:wait` into e.g. `cursor:help` after hovering n seconds (loading time for tooltip) without scripting?

Tags: css, svg, tooltip, svg-animate

There has been a question about changing the cursor using before on this site, but it [asked for a solution using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175740/javascript-cursor-change-and-change-back-again), and it wasn't specific about when to trigger the action to change the cursor.

My question is about SVG and CSS/SMIL **without** the use of other scripting languages such as Javascript.

When hovering over a certain object, how to change the cursor from `cursor:wait` into e.g. `cursor:help`? The change should be triggered after an exact amount of seconds of being hovered over the object.

The use-case is clearly presented in a  minimal snippet below.

## **MWE** SNIPPET

```css
#MOUSE_OVER_THESE{
  cursor:wait;
}
```

```html
<svg id="SVG"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="250"
  height="175"
  viewBox="0 0 250 175">

<text font-size="10" x="10" y="20">
<tspan
  x="10" dy="0">Hover over the objects below. Can the cursor</tspan><tspan
  x="10" dy="12">change from "cursor:wait" into e.g. "cursor:help"</tspan><tspan
  x="10" dy="12.5">after about 1 second, (which will be right</tspan><tspan
  x="10" dy="12.5">about when the tooltip appears on certain</tspan><tspan
  x="10" dy="12.5">browsers) without using any scripting language?</tspan></text>

<g id="MOUSE_OVER_THESE">

<rect x="50" y="100" width="60" height="50" fill="red">
<title>This is a tooltip.</title>
</rect>
<rect x="150" y="100" width="60" height="50" fill="blue">
<title>This is another tooltip.</title>
</rect>

</g>

</svg>
```

I can not afford to use scripting languages such as Javascript, so I am wondering if there is a more native SVG with CSS/SMIL approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick using transition and a hidden element.

**UPDATE**

*The mouse need to be moved slightly in order to see the cursor change*

```css
.hide {
  transition:1s visibility 1s;
  cursor:wait;
}
.hide:hover {
  visibility:hidden;
}

#MOUSE_OVER_THESE {
    cursor:help;
}
#MOUSE_OVER_THESE:hover + .hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<svg id="SVG"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="250"
  height="175"
  viewBox="0 0 250 175">

<text font-size="10" x="10" y="20">
<tspan
  x="10" dy="0">Hover over the objects below. Can the cursor</tspan><tspan
  x="10" dy="12">change from "cursor:wait" into e.g. "cursor:help"</tspan><tspan
  x="10" dy="12.5">after about 1 second, (which will be right</tspan><tspan
  x="10" dy="12.5">about when the tooltip appears on certain</tspan><tspan
  x="10" dy="12.5">browsers) without using any scripting language?</tspan></text>

<g id="MOUSE_OVER_THESE">
<rect x="50" y="100" width="60" height="50" fill="red">
<title>This is a tooltip.</title>
</rect>
<rect x="150" y="100" width="60" height="50" fill="blue">
<title>This is another tooltip.</title>
</rect>
</g>
<rect class="hide" x="50" y="100" width="160" height="50" fill="transparent"></rect>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If your snippet ran correctly, on which browser please?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen it should run in all the browsers because am not using any particular CSS ... by they way am testing on Chrome and FF

Comment: The cursor is not changing as far as I tested on FF and IE (using the snippet shown at the bottom of your answer, on this webpage). It stays shown as `"cursor:wait"`.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen it's working, but in FF we have to slightly move the mouse to see the new cursor ... I guess the rendring of the cursor is made in each mouse move

Comment: I see. Do you think there could be a workaround for that issue?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen am thinking ;) by the way I don't think it's an issue but a normal behavior

Comment: @TermaniAfif Another issue I've found is that the tooltip is not shown during the whole of the `"cursor:wait"`period, no matter how long you keep your mouse positioned (Mac, both in FF, Safari and Chrome).